# N*M table with plots in PyQt

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside, pyqtgraph

I am trying to create a table with a plot inside each cell. Also, multiple cells have to be selectable and clickable to call table context menu.

I have a solution, but it takes too much time when there are 20+ cells in the table. How can I make it faster?

[Screenshot with how it should work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cE6PZ.jpg)

My current solution:

1. Create pyqtgraph and export it to bytes variable
2. Use QStyledItemDelegate and painter.drawImage method to paint that image in each cell

Here is a simplified version of what I currently do:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QTableView, QStyledItemDelegate, QMenu, QHeaderView
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, Qt, QAbstractTableModel
import pyqtgraph as pg
import pyqtgraph.exporters as exporters

RESULTS = {
    'cvar1':{
        'rvar1':[1, 2, 3, 4],
        'rvar2':[8, 2, 5, 7]
        },
    'cvar2':{
        'rvar1':[6, 3, 1, 7],
        'rvar2':[9, 2, 7, 4]
    }
    }

class PreviewDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        # data is our preview object
        data = index.model().data(index, Qt.DisplayRole)
        if data is None:
            return

        # option.rect holds the area we are painting on the widget (our table cell)
        # scale our pixmap to fit
        scaled = data.scaled(
            option.rect.width(),
            option.rect.height(),
            aspectRatioMode=Qt.KeepAspectRatio,
        )
        # Position in the middle of the area.
        x = (option.rect.width() - scaled.width()) / 2
        y = (option.rect.height() - scaled.height()) / 2

        painter.drawImage(option.rect.x() + x, option.rect.y() + y, scaled)

    def sizeHint(self, option, index):
        # All items the same size.
        return QSize(300, 200)


class PreviewModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # .data holds our data for display, as a list of Preview objects.
        self.charts = []

    def data(self, index, role):
        try:
            data = self.charts[index.column()][index.row()]
        except IndexError:
            # Incomplete last row.
            return

        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return data   # Pass the data to our delegate to draw.

    def columnCount(self, index):
        return 2

    def rowCount(self, index):
        return 2


class ResMatrix(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.results = RESULTS
        self.createMatrix()

    def createMatrix(self):
        plot_table = QTableView()
        delegate = PreviewDelegate()
        plot_table.setItemDelegate(delegate)
        self.model = PreviewModel()
        plot_table.setModel(self.model)
        plot_table.setMinimumSize(600, 600)
        plot_table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch)
        plot_table.verticalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch)
        

        self.model.charts = []
        self.generate_charts_and_add_to_model()
        self.model.layoutChanged.emit()

        self.setCentralWidget(plot_table)
        self.show()

    def generate_charts_and_add_to_model(self):
        for col_var in self.results.keys():
            col_var_charts = []
            for row_var in self.results[col_var].keys():
                pg_plot = self.compose_pg_plot(col_var, row_var)
                pg_plot_as_image = self.pg_plot_to_image_bytes(pg_plot)
                col_var_charts.append(pg_plot_as_image)
            self.model.charts.append(col_var_charts)
    
    def compose_pg_plot(self, cvar, rvar):
        plot = pg.PlotWidget()
        curve = pg.PlotDataItem(x=range(4), y=self.results[cvar][rvar])
        plot.addItem(curve)
        return plot

    def pg_plot_to_image_bytes(self, pg_plot):
        exp = exporters.ImageExporter(pg_plot.plotItem)
        exp.parameters()['width'] = 800
        return exp.export(toBytes=True)
    
    def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
        menu = QMenu(self)
        menu.addAction('Action 1')
        menu.exec(event.globalPos())


if __name__=='__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ResMatrix()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: please show what you have tried so far...

Comment: If the data of those plot doesn't change often, just cache the image data in a QPixmap or QPicture.

Comment: Edited post to show what I've done. Caching image data is great idea, thanks! I can do it with plots data calculation since it is long enough for user to not notice.